# 1995 Mercury Grand Marquis, loud whine corresponding to engine revving

Tags: engine, noise, car, grand-marquis

My '95 Grand Marquis (or as I like to call it, a Grandma Rquis) is suddenly very loud.  There doesn't seem to be any issue with the performance, and when it's idling, it's as quiet as can be. I'm wondering if there is a vacuum or air leak or if it's something else.

I've recorded audio of it. I hope links are permitted here. Any help would be great!  I'm hoping to avoid a costly repair, though I'm going to take it in to the mechanic tomorrow.

[Here's the audio upload](https://soundcloud.com/kate_sedgwick/what-is-the-issue)

EDIT: Also, the sound is coming directly from under the hood. It's impossible for me to tell where since I don't have anyone to hit the gas for me while I listen.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though the clutch for the fan has gone out and is now stuck, causing the fan to operate *all the time* (no slippage occurring). You can check to see if this is the case by opening your hood **without the engine running and cold**, grab the fan blade, and rotate the fan. If the fan doesn't rotate or rotate easily, this is most likely your issue.